# problem with pagination in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, production, will-paginate

I upload to production my page. In localhost, the page, run OK but in Production produce this error in dashboard index.

Passenger error

```
Processing DashboardController#index (for 190.19.21.199 at 2011-03-04 06:00:27) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"dashboard"}

NoMethodError (undefined method `to_i' for {:page=>nil}:Hash):
  searchlogic (2.4.19) lib/searchlogic/active_record/association_proxy.rb:14:in `send'
  app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:6:in `index'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:321:in `start_request_handler'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `send'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:270:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `spawn_rails_application'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `spawn_rails_application'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.0) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.0) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

DAshboard Index view

```
<% content_for :header do -%>
    <% unless current_user.nil? %>
        Mi Cuenta
    <% else %>
        Ingrese al sistema
    <% end %>
<% end -%>

<% unless current_user.nil? %>
    <% unless @movements.blank? %>
        <h2>Balance</h2>
        <%= get_total_balance(current_user) %>

        <h2>Ultimos movimientos</h2>
        <table>
          <th>Fecha</th>
          <th>Debite</th>
          <th>Acredite</th>
          <th>Total</th>
          <% @movements.each do |m| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= m.date.to_date %></td>
                <td><%= m.debit %></td>
                <td><%= m.credit %></td>
                <td><%= m.balance %></td>
              </tr>
          <% end %>
        </table>
        <%= will_paginate @movements %>
    <% else %>
        No hay movimientos para mostrar
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <div style="width: 40%; margin: 0 auto;">
      <%= render :partial => 'sessions/new' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

index controller

```
def index
  @movements = current_user.person.saving.movements.paginate :page => params[:page] || 1 unless current_user.nil? || current_user.person.saving.movements.blank?
end
```

However I use pagination with will paginate through the page. This pagination run OK but no in dashboard index. I see the page once. however i tried to enter again. Produce this error.

Thanks in advice

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `index` method in your Dashboard controller?

Comment: @dmarkow Ok now i edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your action:

```
@movements = current_user.person.saving.movements.paginate :page => params[:page] if current_user.present?
@movements = [] if current_user.blank?
```

You can probably get rid of `@movements = [] if current_user.blank?` since you are checking for the existence of current_user in your view anyway.

And this in your view:

```
<% if @movements.length > 0 %>
    <h2>Balance</h2>
    <%= get_total_balance(current_user) %>

    <h2>Ultimos movimientos</h2>
    <table>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Debite</th>
      <th>Acredite</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <% @movements.each do |m| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= m.date.to_date %></td>
            <td><%= m.debit %></td>
            <td><%= m.credit %></td>
            <td><%= m.balance %></td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
    <%= will_paginate @movements %>
<% else %>
    No hay movimientos para mostrar
<% end %>
```

How does that work?

Comment: Excuse me more later I try your solution.Now I work in other project. Thank you very much.